# SQL - join selected data or table for conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, inner-join

I have SQL tables for users and relationships, like
users{ID, name, email}
relationships{ID, uid, relid, type}

I want to get all "friends" ID, name and email (by current user ID) by SQL, using JOIN or whatever.

If using join is it better to JOIN the table of users and select relationships or select relationships and join users?

something like this (I invented now, i use a bit diferrent tables and code, sorry for errors)

1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ID, u.name, u.email FROM users u JOIN relationships r ON (r.uid = 1 OR r.relid = 1) AND r.type = 1 WHERE u.ID = r.uid OR u.ID = r.relid
```

2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ID, u.name, u.email FROM relationships r JOIN users u ON r.uid = u.ID OR r.relid = u.ID = 1 WHERE r.uid = u.ID OR r.related = u.ID
```

---

Edit:
I use DISTINCT becouse when I select users whoose IDs equals to r.uid or r.related, I also get the current user (uid + related) for every relation. DISTINCT should unique the users? I'm beginner and found this on stackoverflow.

So, is it better to select from users and join relations or select relations and join users?

BTW: I quite like the answer with UNION

Answer (score 1):

You can union the users where user is in the `uid` and in the `relid`.

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN relationships AS rel
ON users.ID = rel.uid
WHERE users.ID = 500

UNION

SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN relationships AS rel
ON users.ID = rel.relid
WHERE users.ID = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `DISTINCT` but it looks like you just want to select all the rows from the relationships table (the friends), and then join their details from the users table.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email
FROM relationships r
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = r.uid
WHERE r.uid = 12345
```